# Designing a hybrid RF ampilifier with tube and transistors

Tags: transistors, amplifier, rf, vacuum-tube

I have an 807 vacuum tube and I want to design a RF power amplifier with it.

Since I have only one tube so I want to use transistors for the rest of the power amplifier circuit.

The 807 tube will be used in the final stage and transistors will be used in the pre-amp stages.

I do not have any previous experience in tube based amplifier design, but I have done transistor amplifiers. The output power needs to be 10-20 W. I have a QRP CW transmitter that produces about 800mW on 40m. I am planning to use this tube amplifier with that transmitter.

[807 tube datasheet](http://www.r-type.org/pdfs/807.pdf)

Comment: So is this supposed to be for 6-meter band? What's the plan? It may help if you write a little more.

Comment: Please link to the data sheet for the tube.

Comment: Planning to use for 40 m band

Comment: I have edited my post to include link to 807 tube datasheet

Comment: Is this an old tube? or a modern clone? Old tubes should be checked for good vacuum, and checked for good cathode emission current and checked for a conducting filament. Old tubes whose getters are saturated become gassy, and usually glow purple (not good).

Comment: Have a look at this old 75W transmitter. It uses a 1625 tube, which is a 12V filament version of the 6V 807: http://www.w7ekb.com/glowbugs/projects/inexpensive75wattxmitter.pdf

Comment: @glen_geek That sure takes me back. That's the construction technique I started learning when first into radio as a kid. Those multi-gang capacitors are a bit hard to find, these days, though! Also, I see the 1625 is a tetrode, not a pentode. (Pentode has higher gain and no kink.) To the OP, glen's catch is an 80-meter unit, so you can't copy directly from it. But the basic ideas are there. Regardless, you'll need to work out how to use transistors to drive the 807 pentode final and I don't think it will be  entirely easy to select the right parts for that.

Comment: @jonk me too (re-built an old ARC-5 2-tube transmitter). The Russians sell "new, old-stock" versions of 807, 1625 tubes and call them near-equivalents. I think the OP's 1W transmitter could likely drive the grid directly, perhaps with an impedance matching LC network, along with a 50-ohm load for his little exciter...no transistors necessary - after all, it'll be running Class-C for CW. That article does include data for 40M.

Comment: @glen_geek Thanks for the link. I also found something more like this:

Comment: This [link](https://www.qsl.net/k5dh/6ag7_807.html)  and this [link](http://people.physics.anu.edu.au/~dxt103/valves/807/) . The tube is not used. Its 40 year old stock but new. I am not gonna copy directly. I have to re design all the coils to work in 40 m and also I have to design a buffer stage that will drive the tube.

Comment: Now that I know its not impossible to do, I will start by doing some spice simulation first.